# Getting an "L buffer is too small && 0" error from strcpy_s -- trying to make an overloaded + operator

Tags: c++, class, strcpy

I'm trying to write a simple version of the string class (for practice), and I have everything working except the overloaded + operator.

The line "  strcpy_s(temp, strlen(stringPtr) + 1, stringPtr); " keeps throwing an exception. I assume strcat_s will too.

Any advice?

```
MyString MyString::operator+(const MyString & other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {

        char * temp = new char[strlen(stringPtr) + strlen(other.stringPtr) + 1];
        strcpy_s(temp, strlen(stringPtr) + 1, stringPtr);
        strcat_s(temp, strlen(other.stringPtr) + 1, other.stringPtr);

        delete[]stringPtr;
        stringPtr = temp;

        delete[]temp;

    }
    return this->stringPtr;
}
```

If it helps, stringPtr is being passed "bob," and other.stringPtr is being passed "sally."

Comment: `stringPtr = temp; delete[] temp;` Now `stringPtr` is garbage (an indeterminate value). Your attempt to use it in `return this->stringPtr` has undefined behavior.

Comment: What is the point of the `if (this != &other)` check?

Comment: @melpomene Thanks! Fixed. Unfortunately it's still giving the error.
I put (this != &other) for the edge case of accidentally assigning something to itself.

Comment: What do you mean, assigning? `+` is not assignment.

Comment: @melpomene You're right. I might've gotten my wires crossed there..

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: (sorry, don't know how to format on here yet)

Comment: Don't post it in a comment. Edit your question to include it.

Comment: That's far from complete (or minimal, really).

Comment: What do you think the parameters to `strcpy_s` are?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the same size to both functions.

```
MyString MyString::operator+(const MyString & other)
{
    size_t newSize = strlen(stringPtr) + strlen(other.stringPtr) + 1;
    char * temp = new char[newSize];
    temp[0] = 0;
    strcpy_s(temp, newSize, stringPtr);
    strcat_s(temp, newSize, other.stringPtr);

    //I'm assuming your constructor makes a copy.....    
    MyString ret(temp);
    delete[] temp;
    return ret;
}
```

You might look at [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) for more info on a better way to implement some operators. E.g., `operator+` is often implemented in terms of `operator+=`.

Comment: Note, however, that you **know** that the allocated array is large enough for the concatenated strings, so the "secure" checks are redundant. `strcpy` and `strcat` are just as "safe" here.